# Are questions which require constant updating fit for our sites?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, question-quality

Are questions that will likely require constant updating to remain valid fit for the site?

This is the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37628/3804) that sparked our discussion on Sci-Fi chat, but I think it's broad enough to be covered here:

What I worry about is this, which I stated in our chat:

> Say you come to the site looking for an answer to that question in 2030. You see it's been asked, and find out it's Bela Lugosi. You merely skip off none the wiser that Justin Bieber has taken to staring in twilight-esque vampires movies and now holds the title
> We've just given the wrong answer on the topic. The question requires updating to be valid, where as all the points in the GoT question should remain valid.
> ~[Me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10158202#10158202)

(The GoT reference is to a Game of Thrones question with lots of *partial* answers, similar to a question constantly being answered with 'newer' answers)

So do these questions fit here? Are there better examples from other sites? How do/should these get handled?

I've put it on hold for now but the voices on our chat seem split.

Comment: That is why *What is the best technology/library/framework for...* questions or software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: [the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) is a outdating question example that falls under that category.

Comment: @juergend Is that an exception then?

Comment: Yes, the book guide is an exception (see the highly upvoted comment there). Asking a new similar question would get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers become obsolete all the time, this is certainly something to be aware of and we should try to keep them updated if we can. But it is also unavoidable, there will always be new technologies that replace the current ones, or new evidence to support different conclusions.

So I would argue that the danger of becoming obsolete is not a valid reason to close a question. Many answers are only valid for a certain time, this is a fact we have to be able to deal with. But there are still some cases where this becomes a real problem. If the question itself is useful and interesting, this is something we have to deal with in my opinion and we should try to accomodate those question. The exception would be extremely localized questions.

The actual problem with your example is that it is a trivia question. It asks for a trivial and useless fact, and I don't think it is a useful question for a Q&A format. SE is not the place for movie trivia, the danger of becoming obsolete that quickly is not the biggest problem of that question.

Answer (score 3):

John O's [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37628/which-actor-or-actress-has-played-a-vampire-the-most-in-unrelated-films-televisi#comment71348_37628) notwithstanding, the linked question essentially asks for a list. It just happens to be a list containing a single entry. Such questions are not a good fit because, as you noted, the list can change over time.  Additionally, other people may maintain different lists. (The question doesn't specific whether the OP wants to know only about *American* actors. 'Films' are not defined--just Hollywood movies, or are indies or web videos also counted? etc).

However, to address your broader question about answers that need to be updated, there are certainly questions that *are* a good fit. On Stack Overflow, for example, questions about a particular software version are allowed. The answer will not necessarily apply to all future version, but it will continue to be useful to people stuck on the old version. In such questions, it is helpful to be explicit; state the specific version of software to which the answer is applicable. For the sake of completeness, additional details can be added as new version are released, but the original answer will still apply to the original question.

Specificity would been helpful in the linked answer: your comment addresses that nicely:

> Putting it on hold until you can specify a time period or some other qualifying constraint.

When proper constraints are added to the question, the answer can remain true at any arbitrary point in the future.

Comment: It does not ask for a list. It asks for a single item. The points you make in the rest of the answer could be made without this odd claim.